# How do I disable username prefixes on mySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, database, cpanel

I know of the potential risks.

The only "useful" thing I've been able to find after Google-ing is [this](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/DisableDbPrefix), on the cPanel website, which has no context whatsoever.

Does anyone know how to do this?

My version of cPanel is 11.32.2 (build 28).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DB Preﬁxing is determined by the database_preﬁx value deﬁned in
>   /var/cpanel/cpanel.conﬁg.

- • A value of “1” denotes that DB Preﬁxing is enabled and will emulate
  preﬁxing behavior prior to DB Mapping.
- • A value of “0” denotes that    DB Preﬁxing is disabled and all
  database resources created by cPanel     accounts will be  created
  literally as requested.
- • The absence of a    database_preﬁx deﬁnition will behave as if a
  value of “1” existed.

Manually modifying cpanel.conﬁg is HIGHLY DISCOURAGED and can produce unexpected behaviors.  WHM provides 
the necessary UI for setting DB Preﬁxing to “0,” “Off” but forr Cpanel you have to do it manually .

PS :

Operating cPanel systems with Preﬁxing “Off” can introduce an artiﬁcially frequent occurrence of “name collision” when 
creating cPanel accounts and cpuser database resources.  Because arbitrary names are allowed, the probability that 
common names are requested will increase and therefore the denial to use those names will also increase

Comment: That's fine. It's only me that has access to my website anyway. Do you happen to know how I gain access to the config file? I can't see the path through an FTP client.

Comment: If you are using sharing hosting , you probably can't access it. the admin will not allow you to access config file.

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently my hosting plan doesn't include access to WHM or these settings. Thanks anyway, though.

Answer (score 1):

In WHM, there's a section of the menu called `SQL Services`.

Go into it, and then find: `Disable Database Prefix`.

This page has a screenshot of that screen: http://kb.iweb.com/entries/21073657-how-can-i-repair-my-databases

Comment: Edit: Nevermind. It didn't occur to me straight away that WHM is its own site. Thanks, I'll try that now.